# Performance testing my PHP / MySQL Application for AWS

Tags: php, mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am writing a PHP application which uses MySQL in the backend. I am expecting about 800 users a second to be hitting our servers, with requests coming from an iOS app.

The application is spread out over about 8 diffrenet PHP scripts which are doing very simple SELECT queries (occasionally with 1 join) and simple INSERT queries where I'm only inserting one row at a time (with less than 10kb of data per row on average). Theres about a 50/50 split between SELECTS and INSERTS.

The plan is to use Amazon Web Services and host the application on EC2s to spread the CPU load and RDS (with MySQL) to handle the database, but I'm aware RDS doesn't scale out, only up. So, before committing to an AWS solution, I need to benchmark my application on our development server (not a million miles of the medium RDS solution spec) to see roughly how many requests a second my application and MySQL can handle (for ballpark figures) - before doing an actual benchmark on AWS itself.

I believe I only really need to performance test the queries within the PHP, as EC2 should handle the CPU load, but I do need to see if / how RDS (MySQL) copes under that many users.

Any advice on how to handle this situation would be appreciated.

Thank-you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Apache Benchmark? Should do the job here. Also I've heard good things about [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) but haven't tested yet.

Comment: I rolled with Siege and CurlLoader in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 800 user hits per second, it could be a good idea to consider sharding to begin with. Designing and implementing sharding right at the beginning will allow you to start with a small number of hosts, and then scale out more easily later. If you design for only one server, even if for now it will handle the load, pretty soon you will need to scale up and then it will be much more complex to switch to a sharding architecture when the application is already in production.